# Creating Custom Timeframes

Tags: pine-script

I've seen how on many indicators using moving averages people easily set it up for custom timeframes. I have an indicator that simply plots Long and Short signals, not moving averages. I want the indicator to show me those signals based on whatever timeframe I set it to regardless of my chart timeframe. I haven't found a clear answer to this yet and appreciate any guidance that can be offered.

Example: How do I get the following signals to only show up on the 1H no matter what timeframe my chart is set to?:

```
long = high[2] >= high[1] and high[1] >= high[0] and low < ema37
short = high[2] <= high[1] and high[1] <= high[0] and high > ema37
```

Comment: I think you might be interested to use [security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function

Comment: Yes but I'm not sure how it would work specifically with my code. See new example above.